# How do I manage automatic backups with oracle?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle11gr2, rman

I'm following the tutorial from [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/toc.htm). And I see that the preferred way to manage the backup/recovery processes is by using RMAN. I've started practicing with it (I mean, by sql*plus cli).

But I really don't see how I can automate the process.

Then I saw that in sql developer dba panel, there are some options for working with RMAN. I really don't understand how to use them (I didn't even create e backup) and I couldn't find any tutorial about that.

So can somebody tell me the way how to manage automatic backups through sql developer? Of course if there is a way how to achieve this. If not, what do you suggest me?

Comment: Use [cron to automate rman jobs](http://dcs-coredba.blogspot.in/2011/11/shell-script-to-schedule-cron-for.html) if you're on *nix. Alternatively, use [dbms.job_scheduler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN12385)

Comment: I think you expect something like that: http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/03/rman-in-oracle-sql-developer/

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking specifically for something on SQL Dev, than you should know that from version 3.* and up, they have added a DBA panel (just go to View->DBA or DB Navigator). From there, you can schedule RMAN jobs using a pre-configured script: [RMAN in Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/03/rman-in-oracle-sql-developer/).